# Checking and granting role in Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to create a factory contract which is used to mint ERC721 tokens, at two different prices depending on whether it's during presale.

I'm using the Access library from OpenZeppelin, and have my contract set up with two roles (plus the default administrator role). Some lines are excluded for brevity:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol";
import "./Example.sol";

contract ExampleFactory is AccessControl {
  // ...

  bool public ONLY_WHITELISTED = true;
  uint256 public PRESALE_COST = 6700000 gwei;
  uint256 public SALE_COST = 13400000 gwei;
  uint256 MAX_PRESALE_MINT = 2;
  uint256 MAX_LIVE_MINT = 10;
  uint256 TOTAL_SUPPLY = 100;

  // ...

  bytes32 public constant ROLE_MINTER = keccak256("ROLE_MINTER");
  bytes32 public constant ROLE_PRESALE = keccak256("ROLE_PRESALE");
  
  // ...

  constructor(address _nftAddress) {
    nftAddress = _nftAddress;

    // Grant the contract deployer the default admin role: it will be able
    // to grant and revoke any roles
    _setupRole(DEFAULT_ADMIN_ROLE, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(ROLE_MINTER, msg.sender);
    _setupRole(ROLE_PRESALE, msg.sender);
  }

  function mint(uint256 _mintAmount, address _toAddress) public payable {
    // If the user doesn't have the minter role then require payment
    if (hasRole(ROLE_MINTER, msg.sender) == false) {
        if (ONLY_WHITELISTED == true) {
            // If still in whitelist mode then require presale role & enough value
            require(hasRole(ROLE_PRESALE, msg.sender), "address is not whitelisted");
            require(msg.value >= PRESALE_COST * _mintAmount, "tx value too low for quantity");
        } else {
            require(msg.value >= SALE_COST * _mintAmount, "tx value too low for quantity");
        }
    }

    // Check there are enough tokens left to mint
    require(canMint(_mintAmount), "remaining supply too low");

    Example token = Example(nftAddress);
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < _mintAmount; i++) {
        token.mintTo(_toAddress);
    }
  }

  function canMint(uint256 _mintAmount) public view returns (bool) {
    if (hasRole(ROLE_MINTER, msg.sender) == false) {
        if (ONLY_WHITELISTED == true) {
            require((_mintAmount <= MAX_PRESALE_MINT), "max 2 tokens can be minted during presale");
        } else {
            require((_mintAmount <= MAX_LIVE_MINT), "max 10 tokens can be minted during sale");
        }
    }

    Example token = Example(nftAddress);
    uint256 issuedSupply = token.totalSupply();
    return issuedSupply < (TOTAL_SUPPLY - _mintAmount);
  }
}
```

There are a couple of different paths to mint:

- If the user has `ROLE_MINTER`, they can mint without payment or limits
- If `ONLY_WHITELISTED` is `true`, the transaction must have enough value for presale price, and they must have `ROLE_PRESALE`
- If `ONLY_WHITELISTED` is `false`, anyone can mint

I've written a script to test minting:

```
const factoryContract = new web3Instance.eth.Contract(
  FACTORY_ABI,
  FACTORY_CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  { gasLimit: '1000000' }
);

console.log('Testing mint x3 from minter role')
try {
  const result = await factoryContract.methods
    .mint(3, OWNER_ADDRESS)
    .send({ from: OWNER_ADDRESS });
  console.log('  ✅  Minted 3x. Transaction: ' + result.transactionHash);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('    Mint failed')
  console.log(err)
}
```

Running this successfully mints 3 tokens to the factory owner. No value is attached to this call, and it's minting more than the maximum, so in order for it to be successful it has to follow the `ROLE_MINTER` path.

However, if I call `hasRole` from the same address, the result is `false` which doesn't make sense.

```
const minterHex = web3.utils.fromAscii('ROLE_MINTER')
const result = await factoryContract.methods.hasRole(minterHex, OWNER_ADDRESS).call({ from: OWNER_ADDRESS });
// result = false
```

If I try to run the test mint script from another address (with no roles) it failed as expected, which suggests roles are working but I'm using `hasRole` wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const minterHex = web3.utils.fromAscii('ROLE_MINTER')
```

This JS snippet returns the **hex representation** of the `ROLE_MINTER` string: `0x524f4c455f4d494e544552`

```
bytes32 public constant ROLE_MINTER = keccak256("ROLE_MINTER");
```

But this Solidity snippet returns the **`keccak256` hash** of the `ROLE_MINTER` string: `0xaeaef46186eb59f884e36929b6d682a6ae35e1e43d8f05f058dcefb92b601461`

So when you're querying the contract if the `OWNER_ADDRESS` has the role `0x524f4c455f4d494e544552`, it returns `false` because this address doesn't have this role.

---

You can calculate the hash using the `web3.utils.soliditySha3()` function ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/web3-utils.html#soliditysha3)).

```
const minterHash = web3.utils.soliditySha3('ROLE_MINTER');
const result = await factoryContract.methods.hasRole(minterHash, OWNER_ADDRESS).call();
```

Also note that the OpenZeppelin [hasRole()](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.3.2/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol#L83) function doesn't check for `msg.sender`, so you don't need to specify the caller inside the `call()` function. Just the 2nd argument of the `hasRole()` as the account that you're asking about their role.